# .bashrc function is not working on Cygwin

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin

I recently installed last version of Cygwin. Right now I'm just configuring some alias and functions to use. Cygwin is reading the `.bashrc` file correctly, because some alias are working, I just have a problem with this function:

```
sublime () {
    cygstart "c:/Program Files (x86)/Sublime Text 2/sublime_text.exe" "`cygpath -w $1`" 
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that Cygwin let me do something like this:

```
tom@tom-pc ~
$ sublime myfile.ext
```

Instead of this:

```
tom@tom-pc ~
$ cygstart "c:/Program Files (x86)/Sublime Text 2/sublime_text.exe" myfile.ext
```

How can I solve this problem? I have tried to use single quotes and escape the path string and nothing... Also don't know which programming language is used to execute this functions, so I can't fix this.

Comment: don't forget to quote `$1` too: `cygstart ... "$(cygpath -w "$1")"`

Comment: yes, I had that issue before ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Edit: Answer completely revised after comment thread*

Looks like the problem is that your `.bashrc` has two parts separated by `[[ "$-" != *i* ]] && return`. The first part is executed for all shells, the second part is executed for interactive shells only. The function definition was placed in the second part and thus the function is not defined in non-interactive shells.

Solution: Put `sublime () { ... }` before the `return` line.

Comment: yes, sorry... the line wasn't complete (check edit) ;)

Comment: So how does it fail? What's the actual problem?

Comment: I'm getting **-bash: sublime: couln't find that order** on the shell

Comment: `couln't find that order` is not a bash error. What's the real error message?

Comment: I don't know, I'm working under Windows, and this is a configuration file, but the lines before are working. How can I know the real error?

Comment: By looking at the terminal and copy/pasting the error message.

Comment: .bashrc: line 27: return: only you can use `return in a function or` I have commented that line: `[[ "$-" != *i* ]] && return` and is working now! :D

Comment: Well, that was pointless. For the record, the actual error message was `-bash: sublime: command not found` (probably in a foreign language and "couln't find that order" was a bad translation attempt).